# unable to use "create_graphics_screen" in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am following a tutorial on pygame. here is the link->[tutorial](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/MoveIt.html)
On trying the code from tutorial I am getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'create_graphics_screen' is not defined
```

But in the link(tutorial) this is the line of code is given. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import pygame
import sys
background = ["blue50x50.png","green50x50","pink50*50","red50*50","skin50*50","skyblue50*50"]
screen = create_graphics_screen()     # this line generates error.
```

Does "create_graphics_screen" function actually exist in pygame? 
If yes do I need to import something to run it?

Comment: In other places in the tutorial they use `screen = create_screen()` -- which also doesn't exist. In a section titled _First, The Mystery Functions_ it notes: "The other mystery function we saw in the above example was create_screen(). In pygame it is simple to create a new window for graphics. The code to create a 640x480 surface is below" and the code is `pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `create_graphics_screen()` does not exist; replace it [`pygame.display.set_mode(WIDTH, HEIGHT)`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode).

> This function will create a display Surface. The arguments passed in are requests for a display type. The actual created display will be the best possible match supported by the system.
>
> The resolution argument is a pair of numbers representing the width and height. The flags argument is a collection of additional options. The depth argument represents the number of bits to use for color.